# Sum of values of a field based on another field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows.  I need to build a query to find the following.

(`Sum` of feeComponentValue `where feeComponentCalc = 1`) - (`Sum` of feeComponentValue `where feeComponentCalc = 1`) and it should be `group by feeSettingId`

Please help

```
CREATE TABLE `feevalues` (
  `feevaluesId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `feeSettingId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `feeComponentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `feeComponentValue` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feeComponentCalc` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `feevalues`

```
INSERT INTO `feevalues`
(`feevaluesId`, `feeSettingId`, `feeComponentId`, `feeComponentValue`, `feeComponentCalc`) 
VALUES
(27, 29, 1, 1000, 1),
(28, 29, 12, 2000, 1),
(29, 29, 3, 3000, 1),
(30, 29, 4, 4000, 1),
(103, 30, 3, 1000, 1),
(104, 30, 1, 2000, 1),
(105, 30, 3, 3000, 1),
(106, 30, 1, 4000, 1),
(107, 30, 14, 5000, 2),
(108, 30, 2, 6000, 2),
(109, 30, 13, 7000, 2),
(110, 30, 2, 8000, 2),
(111, 31, 1, 1000, 1),
(112, 31, 3, 2000, 1),
(113, 31, 13, 4000, 2),
(114, 31, 2, 3000, 2),
(122, 32, 1, 1, 1),
(123, 32, 3, 3, 1),
(124, 32, 4, 4, 1),
(125, 32, 2, 5, 2),
(126, 32, 14, 6, 2),
(127, 32, 13, 7, 2);
```

--

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for? "(Sum of feeComponentValue where feeComponentCalc = 1) - (Sum of feeComponentValue where feeComponentCalc = 1)" is just subtracting the same value from itself, which is always zero.  Sample output would be ideal, but even a better description could help get an answer.

"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean `...where feeComponentCalc = 2...` in the 2nd case, right?
With conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  feeSettingId,
  sum(case feeComponentCalc when 1 then feeComponentValue else 0 end) -
  sum(case feeComponentCalc when 2 then feeComponentValue else 0 end) as result
from feevalues
group by feeSettingId
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i38UDjCvyVK5e5ZrwkiH9z/0).
Or:

```
select 
  feeSettingId,
  sum(
    case feeComponentCalc 
      when 1 then feeComponentValue 
      when 2 then -feeComponentValue
      else 0 
    end
  ) as result
from feevalues
group by feeSettingId
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i38UDjCvyVK5e5ZrwkiH9z/1).
Results:

```
| feeSettingId | result |
| ------------ | ------ |
| 29           | 10000  |
| 30           | -16000 |
| 31           | -4000  |
| 32           | -10    |
```